# Rewrite single GET variable in folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page
`example.com/art/?artist=name`
that I want to get to be
`example.com/art/name`.  I've tried multiple rewrite conditions and rules, with none working.  Some examples...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /art/index.php?artist=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)artist=(\w+)(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /%2?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```

Another...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)$ /users/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/$ users/index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

I'd love to have an understanding of how it works as well - right now, I have no idea how the .htaccess file actually does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} artist=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^art/$ /art/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - rewrites into `/art/name/?artist=name`

Comment: Because this file is working on my server, test that file is named (point)htaccess and there is no lines before these

Comment: Mine is the exact same.